# SQLAlchemy get query column types

Tags: sqlalchemy

Once you've made a query with `connection.execute(...)`, how do you get the types of the columns. You can get the names with `result.keys()`. Every column in SQL has a type.

This is a query and not a table.

Comment: In a table with schema "create table a (a int)", this returned None.

Comment: In my case sqlite or postgres, but does it matter?

Comment: My apologies. I thought that the various DBAPI layers (e.g., pysqlite, psycopg2) were reasonably consistent in their implementation of [Cursor.description](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#description) but clearly they are not. sqlite does indeed return `None`, while psycopg2 returns `type_code=23` which is the OID for the column type `int4`.

Comment: Also re: "Every column in SQL has a type.". That is not true for SQLite. SQLite historically has not restricted columns to a particular type; it uses "type affinity" to control how it interprets a specific value. More details [here](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: Interesting, can you give an example of a sqlite query where a column has more than one type?

Comment: In your favorite SQLite client, do `create table a (a int);` followed by `insert into a (a) values (1), ('thing');`. Then do `select * from a;` and you will see that both the integer value `1` and the string value `thing` are in the column named "a".